# A Russian girl is asking for 500 euros to get a passport in Russia. Is this a realistic amount of money for a passport fee?

Tags: russia, russian-citizens, scams

I met a girl from Russia and she wants to see Denmark. I told her to meet first in Moscow to know each other better - anyway she asked me for 500 Euro for an international passport (she never had one she says) and a visa for Denmark. All that could be finished within 14 days. I won't send the money anyway but is 14 days realistic for a NEW passport?

Comment: Ah no - I suggested Moscow but she insisted on Denmark (where I live) and asked for a new passport (she is 33 and says she had never one)

Comment: Where in the world did 500 EUR come from?  Adding 'scam' tag.

Comment: Here is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_passport#Issue_Time) says. Sure sounds like a classic honey trap scam. Have you actually seen (real time) video of her, or could it be some big hairy Russian guy you've been talking to.

Comment: She's obviously more interested in getting to Denmark than she is in being with you.

Comment: Yes I know what wikipedia says and normally it takes weeks to get the passport .....

Comment: The 500 Euro came from an agent that wanted to offer her a new passport and a Schengen .... can you get a passport in Russia from a travel agent

Comment: @user40035 I don't know whether one can get a passport from a travel agent in Russia but it sounds very unlikely.  One *certainly cannot* get a Schengen visa from a travel agent.

Comment: One certainly cannot get a Schengen visa from a travel agent - are you sure?? In the Ukraine it's what people normally do but in Russia I don't know. I think you can but the agent just sends your passport to the embassy and returns it to you afterwards

Comment: @user40035 to get a Schengen visa, you must submit an application to the appropriate consulate.  I suppose it's possible for a travel agent to submit the application on your behalf.  However, since a Russian passport seems to cost about EUR 40 and an urgent visa application for Denmark seems to cost about EUR 65 (see http://www.denmarkvac-ru.com/) the figure of EUR 500 implies that your friend is scamming you or else the agent is overcharging and/or scamming her.  I would approach with extreme caution if I were you.

Comment: To the tune of the Monty spam song: Scam, scam, scam, scam! Lovely scam, wonderful scam!

Comment: Mine cost about 30 pounds.

Comment: Not having a travel passport is normal. The EUR 500 sum looks just random. Unless you know "proper channels" (which is most likely illegal) it'd be rather hard to get a new travel passport *and* a visa in 14 days - you cannot apply for a visa until you have a passport in your hands and official requirements say that a travel passport is usually emitted in no longer than one month and that period can be extended to three months in exceptional cases.

Comment: There is no point in paying for someone's (whom you don't even know) ticket, passport, visa, etc. If someone can't pay for it then you can come by yourself. When money is involved even before a relationship begins, it's a huge warning sign.

Answer (score 55):

If you apply by yourself:
The waiting time for getting a International passport is 30 days if you apply in your city (where you're registered) and 120 days if you apply from another Russian city.
Official source: https://www.gosuslugi.ru/pgu/service/10001970310_5.html#!_description

Just if you're going to funerals or if you need to be healed abroad urgently, a passport will be ready for you within 3 days.

It's cost 2000 rub (old type) or 3500 rub (new type) (for citizens over 14 years old) which is around 24 or 41 EUR (today)

But as @IMil mentioned, there are services which claim to get a passport done quicker.

For example: 
http://www.9954000.ru/cont/tarifi-na-oformlenie-zagranichnogo-pasporta-cns-8/#tarify2 
offers it for 4-30 days, for extra 7000-25000 RUB (around 84-300EUR)

Scammers mostly targeting dating web-sites, therefore if the girl from a dating site asks for money it's very likely a scam, because it's a super popular scheme.
Normal Russian girls won't ever ask for money, only gold-diggers and scammers.

Very often you're actually talking to a Russian guy who is sending you a very nicely prepared love messages with sexy girl pictures :)

I wouldn't recommend anyone to look for Russian girls on dating web-sites, better on some interest related web-resources where their reputation is proved by a community.

Even Better would be to come to a small city in Russia (Not Moscow or St.Petersburg), look around there and choose one ;)
Though you better go for "English club" meetings or something like that, as not so many Russian girls in small cities speak English well. (You can find this kind of meetings and groups on vk.com or couchsurfing.com)

Remember there are Russians "earning" lots of money by fooling foreigners to send money for their tickets, passports and some medical operations for relatives and etc...
Don't support scammers by sending them your money.

In the 90's most Russians got scammed at least once or twice, everyone is aware of scammers, but still Russian scammers easily scam Russians again and again. Fooling western people is super easy (because you didn't experience getting scammed as often as Russians). It's good for the Western world that aren't so many Russian scammers speak English yet.

P.S.: I Love Russia, I'm Russian.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there are services which claim to get a passport done in a couple weeks: http://www.9954000.ru/cont/tarifi-na-oformlenie-zagranichnogo-pasporta-cns-8/#tarify2 . This doesn't change the fact that what is going on is an obvious scam attempt.

Comment: "the girl **from a dating site**" (emphasis by myself) - wait, where did that piece of information just come from?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Mostly scam with "500 EUR" shows up on dating web-sites. I used to have a dating web-site ("Mamba" member), I know owners and users of other dating web sites. Many times I heard about the Russian girls asking money for tickets, for renting, for some trouble and etc. Usually scammers target only dating web-sites. Even if this happened not on a dating web-site, I still recommend not to look for Russian girls there.

Comment: @ViacheslavBakshaev: All right. In that case, the answer should state exactly that. As it stands, "the girl from a dating site" sounds like this is a part of the background information given by the OP.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper is it better now? (I'm newbie to express myself in English)

Comment: @ViacheslavBakshaev I am not so convinced of their ineptitude in English: The english phishing and ransomware mails I receive are now frightfully sophisticated, but as German I am relieved that they still cannot fake normal German realistically.

Comment: @ThorstenS. In America, respectable corporations go to pains to use correct English in any public messaging.  So bad English really stands out.  As such, Americans were widely educated to look out for bad English *as a sign* of scam emails.  **Implying ones with proper English were legit.** And Americans fell into the latter habit.  Thus creating a new vulnerability.  Not surprisingly, scammers jumped all over that!  A simple matter of finding one of the near-100 million people on this planet who can speak English correctly.

Answer (score 12):

Don't waste your time. 95% it's scam. 500 EUR is too much for a new passport and a visa. I'd not even bother going to Moscow to see her. It's good you're not going to send money.

Comment: Although Moscow would be worth a trip even if there is no girl.