# Holiday in Uk from Russia

Tags: paperwork

I have a Russian friend who wants to have an a holiday in the Uk  next year ,does anyone know what paper work is required , ie visa , passport etc

Comment: I don't want to jump to conclusions here, but if you're being asked for any money then please see the related question [My online friend is asking for money in order to visit my home country. Is this a legit request or a scam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/my-online-friend-is-asking-for-money-in-order-to-visit-my-home-country-is-this)

Answer (score 4):

A passport is required for virtually all international travel.

For Russian citizens visiting the UK, a visa is required. You can find out what your friend needs to do on the [Apply for a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa) site.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend will need to apply for a [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/russia/tourism).

The UK government website gives a [list of documents required](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).