# Can my Russian girlfriend leave the country if she owes the bank money?

Tags: money, russian-citizens

My Russian girlfriend has already been approved for a visa and bought an airplane ticket. She took a loan of $700 from a Russian bank. She was telling me that she may not be able to leave on December 2nd to fly to the USA because of the $700 loan that she needs to pay off before she can leave. She was told about this a few days ago she has no way to pay it off at this time. Her family doesn't have the money either. What are her options in this short time?

Comment: Please be aware that this situation smells heavily like a scam - please read the question and answers that I've linked to.

Comment: "What are her options?" --> finding another mark sounds like a plan... Obvious scam.

Comment: This is most likely a scam, *but*, yes in fact it is possible that a person will be barred from going abroad if they have outstanding debt or fines in Russia. Not the normal scheduled payment but payment default.

Comment: It is known to happen, but I've never heard it happen for bank loans, only fines owed to the government. Either way, it can always be bypassed by driving to Minsk and flying from there.
All in all, this is probably a scam.

Answer (score 7):

This is almost certainly going to lead to her asking you for money, and is almost certainly a scam. Please see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/104281/4765), as it’s something that gets brought up fairly often.