# I have been emailing a Russian woman for 7 months

Tags: money, russian-citizens, scams

My head tells me it's a scam.  She doesn't have a smart phone so all communication is by email. She has already asked for money for air tickets then proof of money in her bank so that she can leave Russia. She now says that she won't be allowed to leave without paying off her debt.

Can someone leave Russia if they owe money to their bank, like having a mortgage?

Comment: The golden rule is "if you have to ask...".  Yes, its a scam.  Run away, now.

Comment: https://www.gotorussia.com/travel_marriage_info.htm

Comment: http://www.onlinedatingsafetytips.com/russianscammers.cfm

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106046/can-my-russian-girlfriend-leave-the-country-if-she-owes-the-bank-money/106047

Comment: Do you really have to ask? The no skype/no smartphone is a dead giveway, and even then.  they will milk you down as long you have money. Tickets, debts, then father needs a heart surgery, she will have an accident and needs hospital bills paid...

Comment: You don't need a smartphone to have other methods of communication besides email... serious red flag.  (And you know the answer to your question.  The answer is: of course it's a scam.)