# russian women asking for $2000.00 to show athorities she has enough money for her trip

Tags: money, russia, internet, scams

i have met a girl online from rusia. we have been sending massages through my email address.it has now been six weeks since her first message.she uses the internet cafe. she was short $516 american for her airplane ticket. so i sent her $820. canadian. after arriving at the airport, she said the lady in the airport cannot give her the tickets unless she has $2070. in her account to prove she can afford to visit Canada. i think that i am being scammed.

Comment: You are being scammed. That C$820 is gone. Don't throw any more money a this.

Comment: You are. You've lost your 820$.

Comment: You are; [here's a similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/113321/romance-scam-true-or-false-need-answers) among the many here.

Comment: Even assuming its all totally legit (it's not. Obvious scam.)...Why would she be showing up at the airport to buy a ticket?

Comment: "She" is probably not from Russia, and probably not a girl either. She doesn't look like the pictures she sent you.

Answer (score 10):

**Short answer: Stop sending her money and go to the authorities!**

Long answer: This is a known scam to get money out of people who are looking for a loved one. There are a lot of other people who have been scammed the same way as for example travel.SE states [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/my-online-friend-is-asking-for-money-in-order-to-visit-my-home-country-is-this) and [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/113321/romance-scam-true-or-false-need-answers).

Please go to the authorities and try to prevent this women from harming other innocent people and reach out to your bank if there is any way you can get your money back.

I wish you the best of luck finding someone who loves you for what you are and does not want to scam you.

Comment: `I wish you the best of luck finding someone who loves you` So cute :3