# If someone from Russia is leaving to visit the US, do they need plane tickets before they get a visa?

Tags: visas

If someone from Russia is leaving to visit the US, do they need plane tickets before applying for a visa?

Comment: Are you the traveller? This sounds like a potential scam https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/my-online-friend-is-asking-for-money-in-order-to-visit-my-home-country-is-this

Comment: Never get tickets before a visa.  What if you don't get teh visa? You're stuck with the tickets you can't use!

Comment: @MarkMayo unless you're applying for a Chinese visa.

Comment: @dda well there's always exceptions I suppose. Almost never ;)

Comment: Count on China to make things different 

Comment: Although it has been marked as a duplicate of a scam, what if the OP is asking for himself? @jake are you asking for a potential Russian girlfriend trying visiting you?

Comment: @Newton If the asker comes back and says, "No, no, I'm the person who's travelling", we can always reopen the question. However, as I recall from applying for a J-visa a couple of years ago, the US government websites are quite clear about what documents you need and a plane ticket isn't one of them. That being the case, the question should probably be closed anyway: the correct and up-to-date answer is easily available from offical sources, whereas any answer we give is unofficial and could go out of date.