# How can I find out if an airline ticket has been used or cashed in?

Tags: air-travel

How do I find out if an airline ticket for a Delta flight has been used or cashed in? I purchased the ticket for a person in another country to get back to the USA.

Comment: This is a scam.

Comment: Sorry to say, but you've been cashed out.

Comment: How did you pay for it? If by credit card, it might be worth checking out the airline’s policy - potentially they’d only refund to the card used to buy the ticket.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the booking information, such as a ticket number or booking identifier (i.e. PNR, reservation code), and you are the one who purchased the ticket, you should be able to log in to your Delta account to check on the status of the reservation, or call Delta to have the information looked up.

If you did not purchase the ticket yourself or through a travel agent, but gave funds directly to someone else to purchase, you are probably out of luck. Airlines are not in the habit of giving out information about their sales to strangers, even in countries without strong privacy protections in law.

---

As commenters have noted, however, your post has red flags suggesting **you may be the victim of a scam or attempted scam**. There are numerous ways in which scammers try to get you to send money to them. I personally have received a number of variations over the years, including messages supposedly from superiors at work asking me to buy and send gift cards, friends who lost their wallet or passport in a foreign country and need me to wire money, family members who need help processing a windfall, and indeed the proverbial Nigerian prince in exile. See *[My online friend is asking for money in order to visit my home country. Is this a legit request or a scam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281)* for some tips and possible recourse.

Comment: No need to log on to 'your account'. All airlines allow access to the ticket data with the passenger's last name and the booking code.