# Russian citizen visiting the US

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, russian-citizens

How much money does a Russian citizen have to have to visit the US as a Tourist, and does the visitor have to have a certain amount of cash even if that person can stay at a friends house during the visit?

Comment: Are you talking to someone online who claims to be a woman in Russia who wants to visit you but needs money? [It may be a scam.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/104281/3221)

Answer (score 2):

There is no published requirement. The presumption under U.S. law is that every visitor visa applicant is an intending immigrant until they demonstrate otherwise. Therefore, applicants for visitor visas must overcome this presumption by demonstrating:

• That the purpose of their trip is to enter the United States temporarily for business or pleasure;

• That they plan to remain for a specific, limited period;

• Evidence of funds to cover expenses in the United States;

• That they have a residence outside the United States as well as other binding ties that will ensure their departure from the United States at the end of the visit.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html