# How can I tell if a BA flight ticket is fake?

Tags: tickets, british-airways, scams

[image] Is this ticket fake? I’ve tried numerous other things but nothing turned up.

Comment: Have you asked British Airways?

Comment: @Wendy McCall Why do you think it might be a fake? Have to say it doesn’t look like confirmations I’ve had recently from BA, the logo is different for one thing

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143507/how-can-i-tell-if-a-flight-itinerary-is-fake

Comment: It's for last year, so what happened when the ticket holder tried to fly?

Comment: The flight (BA16 SYD-SIN-LHR) actually flew on that date, with the given scheduled times. What are you trying to check? That someone was actually on that flight? Even if the booking was valid it would be difficult to prove that with only that information.

Comment: Doing two Google searches, "British Airways ticket" and "British Airways confirmation" and viewing images, none shown resemble this. Doesn't definitively answer fake or not, but just for your awareness of search methods maybe not considered.

Comment: Possibly related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/my-online-friend-is-asking-for-money-in-order-to-visit-my-home-country-is-this

Comment: This is a photo of a screen, not a ticket.

Answer (score 4):

Valid tickets have either a booking reference (PNR) or a ticket number or both. That is a unique identifier. If there is one on there, you can almost always check the booking on the airline's website or give them a call.

If there is no PNR or ticket number, than it's not really a ticket. Could be a receipt, or an itinerary, or a fake. However, you couldn't use it to check in.

Comment: he was held up so didn’t use it i think it looks fake i think the guy is a scammer that’s why

Comment: @WendyMcCall If someone is telling you "I had a ticket for that flight but I had an issue and now I'm stuck in Australia and I need money and blah blah blah" then the chances of them being a scammer are very high. But without the full story or more details it's difficult to say anything. The picture you include in your post does not prove anything either way. There could have been an actual booking (which may or may not have been used, for whatever reason, and could have been paid and/or refunded, or not), or not.

Comment: The Departure date is shown as February **2020**, almost a year in the past. How can this be relevant to something going on at this moment, or to an assertion that this is a current and valid booking?