# Travelling to Syktyvkar, Russia

Tags: visas, russia, spanish-citizens

Am planning to travel in Syktyvkar, Russia to meet the girl I met on a dating site. What document should I need to apply for a tourist visa? I'm currently residing here in Barcelona, Spain.

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: Has she asked for money?

Comment: I think we just had a question about this and an invite from a "travel company" is needed.

Comment: It depends on your nationality. Check the official portal https://visa.kdmid.ru

Comment: @Harold Banawa Before you proceed too far with this trip, reading this related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/my-online-friend-is-asking-for-money-in-order-to-visit-my-home-country-is-this might give you some food for thought.

Comment: I understand the urge to warn OP of the chance this is a scam, but at least one of these comments sounds like somebody entirely disregarding the possibility that it isn't. Honest Russians do exist, and it's very tiring how often the internet seems not to realise that.

Comment: Don't scams work the other way round and the lady needs money to visit the guy in the west?

Comment: @ChrisH is right. I met my Russian wife online and she has never once asked me for money. These comments are ridiculous and shameful.

Comment: This isn’t a duplicate of the travel company question as OP is two steps before where the travel company question is. That said, a confirmation what your nationality is (it was edited in as Spanish citizenship but the original post only stated resident of Spain) would be helpful for a better answer.

Comment: @AussieJoe I agree with your comment. There is a stereotype out there but equally there’s no doubt scams do exist all over the world so I guess the comments are well-meant, rather than intentionally prejudiced.

Answer (score 5):

There are two Russian embassies in Spain you can contact to apply for a tourist visa.

> 1. Consular department of the Embassy of the Russian Federation in the
>      Kingdom of Spain Address:
>
>    - calle Joaquín Costa, 33, 28002 Madrid
>    - Phone: (8-10-34-91) 411-29-57
>    - Fax: (8-10-34-91) 562-78-30
>    - E-mail: consmd@arrakis.es
>    - Web: http://www.rusmad.mid.ru
>    - Business hours: from Monday to Friday — from 10.00 to 14.00.
>    - Emergency phone number in case of    emergency: +34-91-563-71-92; +34-670-848-773
> 2. Consulate General of the Russian Federation in Barcelona
>
>    - Address: av. Pearson, 34, 08034    Barcelona
>    - Phone: (8-10-34-93) 280-54-32, 280-02-20
>    - Fax: (8-10-34-93)    280-55-41
>    - E-mail: barcelona.mid@mail.ru
>    - Web: http://barcelona.mid.ru
>    - Business hours:  from Monday to Friday — from 10.00 to 13.30
>    - Emergency phone number in case of emergency: +34-609-306-346; +34-647-574-539

They will ask you to fill out an application online. You will need to create an application with a password on [the website of the Consular department of the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of the Russian Federation](https://visa.kdmid.ru/).

> ### The documents you will need, in order to process a Russian tourist visa are:
>
> 1. Your original passport with at least 2 blank visa-designated pages    (passport must be valid for at least 6 months after intended 
>      departure date from Russia).
> 2. Two copies of Russian visa application form, completed and signed.
> 3. Two passport-size photos signed on the back.
> 4. If Tour Group or Cruise Passenger: Letter from tour company or cruise line confirming itinerary and including a copy of the confirmation from authorized Russian travel company which shows the reference number and confirmation number for the visa.
> 5. If Individual Travel: Confirmation of hotel arrangements from authorized Russian travel company, or directly from the Russian hotel, showing reference number and confirmation number for the visa.

You will need a letter of invitation, either from a tour group, or hotel in order to register you as a valid tourist in Russia. If you get a letter of invitation from a tour group business, you can pay online and have it emailed to you. If you get a letter of invitation from a hotel, they can process it online when you email them about it. The hotels can do it for free (usually), whereas tourist groups will charge you a small fee. Good luck!

Comment: Please note the comments on the question, the risk she is not the girl you think she is.

Comment: @Willeke the comments are irrelevant to the underlying question, a tourist visa for Spanish citizens. His business, is his business.

Comment: Just one minor issue in this answer - the girlfriend can't do the invitation for a tourist visa, only accredited tourist agencies/hotels/etc. You can get a *private* visa with an invite from an individual, but the process is much more drawn out and really not worth the hassle.

Comment: @ChrisH you're right, I removed that. The girlfriend can register him at the post office once he arrives but she cannot invite him. Thanks for pointing that out.