# minimum Solvency requirements for a visa to the UK. a 90 day visa is required

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, russian-citizens

I have a friend from Russia who wants to visit the UK on a 90 day visa. what is the minimum amount she needs to prove her solvency

Comment: There isn’t one. And the UK doesn’t issue 90 day visas. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/938632/visit-guidance-v10.0ext.pdf (see page 24)

Comment: This sort of request from a friend in a foreign country is a common scam.  If you don't know this friend well you're probably being scammed.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/my-online-friend-is-asking-for-money-in-order-to-visit-my-home-country-is-this?r=SearchResults