# Can one travel without photo ID on Greyhound buses?

Tags: tickets, lost-documents, greyhound

My friend lost her photo ID and she says that she can go to the bus station and get a ticket anytime without a photo ID I want to bring her to New York Jesus to bring the money I think she's trying to scam me so I was wondering if it is possible to get on a bus without a photo ID

Comment: If I’ve understood your question correctly, you will be buying your friend’s ticket for her to collect. According to https://www.greyhound.com/en/help-and-info/travel-info/bus-travel-faqs she can pick up a ticket at a self-serve kiosk with just the confirmation number. What makes you think she might be trying to scam you?

Comment: Please see this answer.  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166255/friend-needs-help-in-turkey/166258#166258  I suspect a lot of the ideas in it will apply to your case as well.  If you're afraid your friend may be trying to scam you, then there's a good possibility you only _think_ you're talking to your friend.