# Can I help my friend get a Colombian passport from the USA?

Tags: passports, scams, colombia, payment, colombian-citizens

My friend lives in Bogotá, Colombia. Can I help her get a Colombian passport, and can I pay with a credit card from the USA?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It's unclear from your question what your friend's intentions are, or why she would not be able to obtain a passport on her own, assuming she is Colombian by nationality. How long have you known this friend, and have you met in person? I ask because there are a very large number of scams where someone pretends to need money for a visa or some vaguely described fee or tax in order to visit.

Comment: How much money does your friend say is needed to obtain the passport?  The fee in Bogota seems to be 169,000 Colombian pesos, which is about 45 US dollars.

Comment: I hate that I have to ask this, but have you actually met your friend in real life? See [My online friend is asking for money in order to visit my home country. Is this a legit request or a scam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/104281/6188)

Answer (score 8):

I urge you to be extremely careful here, and to follow the advice given elsewhere to [think carefully about if the request is legitimate or a scam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/104281/6188).

If you are certain of your friend's identity and conclude that you do indeed want to help them pay for a passport, you can indeed to so by credit card. According to the [step-by-step instructions on the Colombian government's website](https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/sites/default/files/FOTOS2019/guia_pago_tarjeta_de_credito_1.pdf), you must go to https://tramites.cancilleria.gov.co/apostillalegalizacion/pago/inicioPagoTC.aspx, enter the payment reference number created when your friend applies for their passport, and follow the further instructions there. Note that the URL ends in `.gov.co`, so you can be sure it is a Colombian government website and not some imposter. Given the existence of this site, be especially wary for requests for funds by Western Union or some other non-refundable, non-traceable method.

The cost for a Colombian passport issued in Bogotá is [169,000 Colombian Pesos](https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/tramites_servicios/pasaportes/costos) as of this writing, plus an additional 2,200 pesos for paying by credit card, a total of just over US$45 at current exchange rates. Again, be especially wary of claims that you will have to pay significantly more than this.