# I can't rebook ticket for a different passenger

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings, refunds

I booked  a flight for a friend for Cyprus to Fort Myers FL with my credit card in January 2022,  2 weeks in advance of travel.
He did not take the flight and chose to stay and we no longer are in touch.
I was never reimbursed by him for the airline ticket.
Turkish airlines explained that the ticket can only be rebooked for the passenger on the original ticket and is non refundable.
And now I am out $800.
Is there anyway around this?
It seems  a total waste of an unused ticket.

Comment: You should have bought a refundable ticket (which costs much more than a non-refundable ticket). If you don't use it, is wasted; Turkish lets you rebook the journey, it's already better than nothing...

Comment: Sounds like a classic *’friend’ needs money for airline ticket* scam to me

Comment: Did you mean January 2022 (past), or 2023 (future)?

Comment: Interesting definition of "friend".

Comment: @Traveller This stinks, but what is the scam here? The so-called “friend” just disappeared and the ticket is worthless since the flight wasn’t taken. So who benefits from this “scam?” The airline? Seems like this is more of a really crappy prank than a scam. PS: Unless the “friend” rebooks the ticket? “Turkish airlines explained that the ticket can only be rebooked for the passenger on the original ticket and is non refundable.” Seems like that is the case but is it? My recommendation to the original poster would be to dispute the charge with the credit card company.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 on what grounds?

Comment: @littleadv I mean what is the scam? That the “friend” now has $800 in credit with the airline? A scam typically has a goal with someone losing and someone else benefitting. Who benefits here? Also, “ My recommendation to the original poster would be to dispute the charge with the credit card company.” They should just contact the credit card company and see what can be done. Grounds should be based on what the credit card company says they can do. If they do nothing, oh well! But at least they should try and ask.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 sure, they can call, but disputing the charge will not work since the charge is not fraudulent and is authorized.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Oh come on - scams involving scenarios like the one described in the question abound. Obviously the ‘friend’ benefited, because they have a credit with the airline they can use. Try searching *scams* on TSE or read this, for example https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/my-online-friend-is-asking-for-money-in-order-to-visit-my-home-country-is-this

Comment: @Traveller Fair enough!

Comment: Check if the flight expired or if your "friend" rebooked it. If they have rebooked and used the flight, you are out of luck and have no recourse. if the flight was scheduled on a past date and no one has flown, you can request the refund of some taxes even if the fare is not refundable.Better than nothing. call TK again and ask specifically for "refund of refundable taxes on unused ticket", they'll tell you the amount and how to send it, that being said, they might have something in their terms and conditions like (refundable taxes should be claimed maximum 3 months after flight).they will say

Comment: Section of terms and conditions that might be relevant to you: 11.4.3 In the event the Passenger fails to board the flight, the Passenger will benefit from the refund
of the taxes, airport charges and any other fees which are payable due to the Passenger’s actual
boarding when his/her ticket is no more valid, according to the current regulation.   Link: https://cdn.turkishairlines.com/m/345fdf080801b8ee/original/EN-FR-pdf.pdf . let's hope your "friend" didn't claim it first.

Comment: Is this a friend you have met in person, someone you actually know, or is it someone you met online and have struck up a purely online friendship with?

Answer (score 18):

> And now I am out $800

yes

> Is there anyway around this?

You can sue your "friend", if the court accepts your claim that they owe you - they'd have to repay.

> It seems a total waste of an unused ticket

Not total. First, your friend now has a $800 credit with the airline. Second, you learnt a valuable lesson.

Comment: "First, your friend now has a $800 credit with the airline." – Says who?

Comment: @Mophotla says the OP: "*Turkish airlines explained that the ticket can only be rebooked for the passenger on the original ticket and is non refundable*"

Comment: The flight already took place without the passenger flying. the friend will get nothing of it either now.

Comment: @meego that depends on the airline's policies, it is not at all certain. I know some airlines would allow credit for unused ticket even if it is non-refundable, and looking at what the OP wrote, seems like that's the case here.

Comment: We know the airline is TK who doesn't do that. The answer can be factual and not speculative.

Comment: The ticket can only be rebooked for the original passenger, yes, but by whom? The passenger or by the person who bought the ticket? If it's the latter, then the friend has no credit.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I have yet to see an airline who'd allocate the value to passenger X but only allow booking to payer Y. In fact, in all cases of all the airlines that I'm familiar with the ticket belongs to the passenger named on the ticket, no matter who's name is on the credit card used to pay for it.

Comment: In any case, the OP can cancel the ticket. Non-refundable doesn't mean it cannot be cancelled. And you can (and should) get back the taxes and other fee (it is just a part, but probably the most of the ticket, that it is non-refundable).

Comment: It is not a valuable lesson. If this situation never happened to OP, he would have never learnt the lesson, but he'd be just fine because he would not need the lesson.