# How can I change the location of my fiancé's immigration interview in Africa?

Tags: visas, usa, applications, uganda

What is the current status of the US embassies in Africa regarding changing the location of the immigration interview for my fiance? Are all US embassy locations in Africa able to process the immigration papers, or are some too small? I am in the USA trying to get my fiance here; she is in Kampala, Uganda, but it is too expensive to live there. I was considering changing the interview to Khartoum.

Comment: Kampala is expensive?  Compared to what?  The cost of living in Kampala appears to be 1/3 to 1/2 of that in the US depending on whether you look at an expensive city such as San Francisco or a smaller one such as Billings.  How well do you know your fiancee?  Also, note that [the U.S. Embassy in Kampala does not process immigrant visas. Immigrant visa applicants residing in Uganda must attend an in-person visa interview at the U.S. Embassy in Nairobi, Kenya](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/Supplements/Supplements_by_Post/KMP-Kampala.html).  I smell a scam.

Comment: How is the cost of living in Uganda relevant to changing the interview location? You might want to check out https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/my-online-friend-is-asking-for-money-in-order-to-visit-my-home-country-is-this

Comment: This question is OT for this site.  It belongs on [Expatriates.SE].