# How can I check if this airline ticket is genuine?

Tags: tickets, international-travel, business-travel, scams, travel-agents

Some girl whom I met on fb started chatting & subsequently became friends, After couple of weeks She told me that she is going to revive her Jewelry Business for which she is coming to India. As such this was a sudden decision & being a friend she insisted me to arrange meeting of biggest Jewelers for which my investment of almost INR 200000/ is required. As per our recent whatsapp chat she's currently traveling to India but looking at the ticket I am not sure coz there is no PNR number or any reference number.
She is travelling with British Airways from Heathrow, London to Chatrapati Shivaji Airport Mumbai.
i am attaching the ticket she shared with me for clarity purpose.

Can Someone help in this regard ?

[image]

Comment: Scammer warning. Someone you have not met in person asking for money? That is not good. Ticket information not complete? That is worse. Do not give her any (more) money till you have been able to confirm more details (and even then it sounds fishy.)

Comment: I cannot imagine a situation where I would ask someone I'd known for a couple of weeks for that money.

Comment: This is clearly a scam. BTW: BA139 today flied with Boeing 777. As it did yesterday, and will do tomorrow and has been for as long as I can see in the history.

Comment: Guaranteed fake, they can’t even do basic maths, there are different times all over, and none match the real flight schedule. And the barcode… I hope you haven’t paid a cent because you won’t see any of it again.

Comment: Keep in mind that even if the ticket were real, the purchaser could still cancel it later, possibly even for a full refund if it's a refundable fare. Of course, in this case, the ticket isn't real and this is obviously a scam, but this still would have every hallmark of a scam even if the ticket were real.

Comment: If you had posted this on  [Money.SE], someone would have said “I stopped reading at ‘Some girl whom I met on fb’”

Comment: Please see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/my-online-friend-is-asking-for-money-in-order-to-visit-my-home-country-is-this?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Damila oh common, we don't do that there, we're nice!  Oh, [wait...](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/155522/am-i-being-scammed-after-paying-almost-10-000-to-a-tree-company-not-being-able/155523#155523)

Comment: ‘Some girl’ probably isn’t even a girl

Comment: And as for the currency, INR 200000/- is quite less than GBP 2910.12. So if she really had to invest, she'd have done it herself than book that expensive a ticket.

Comment: I'm always surprised these scams make it to the stage where someone can't tell it's obviously a scam and has to ask around. Based on the Stack Exchange questions, it must be a lucrative business.

Comment: @user253751 The scammers are quite skilled and sift through their targets carefully. I know a lady who lost a LOT of money in a romance scam. Very embarrassing for her. Once their victim is hooked, they keep pushing for more. Sending a bit more money is easier than admitting to yourself the dream is a lie.

Comment: I'm just confused as to what she needs the money for. Does she need to pay this jeweler in order to meet with them? If the none of the other red flags stopped you before this, consider that while travel is expensive, a regular business meeting should be free.

Comment: @user253751 Keep in mind that something which looks obvious for someone, doesn't always look so for everyone else. It took me some time, but I realised there is no such thing as "common sense", beside that which you learned at the school of hard knocks.

Comment: @user253751 From a game theoretic perspective, it is **correct** for scammers to insert such "easily detectable" tells and errors in their materials. Their payoff comes from marks which will go all the way to paying them, and causing those with the sense to say "wtf" to **self-select away** raises their hitrate *per time spent*, which is the scare resource.

Comment: @obscurans so bad scammers make more money? Darwin wouldn't approve! Btw. "Funny" thing here is, this person is probably already in a India, no need for the ticket.

Comment: @obscurans IIRC that theory was actually debunked and it really was just because they make mistakes because they aren't natives of the country they target

Comment: @DonQuiKong  Darwin never objects to "natural selection" which is a thing. (No comments on the usually included other aspect :-) ). Here the selection of the fittest is the selection of a prospect who will likely return best return on effort (as user 2727...) notes.
[[The fittest" is the one that best fits. It's a tautology unless you accept that it's self defining :-) ]]

Comment: @user253751 As a game theorist I would love to read that source. Nevertheless, my point is that it is *theoretically* correct; exhibiting correct behavior without any shred of understanding why it is correct or even of making a choice in the first place doesn't change its benefit to the scammer, nor to the actual natural selection mechanism that can teach people to gravitate towards it. Humans had scientific improvements (tool usage, etc.) long before being able to formalize the scientific method.

Answer (score 90):

This is a scam, 1000%

- All Boeing 747s have been retired back in 2020 from the BA [Fleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Airways_fleet)
- The times are different on the same page (see the 07:40 arrival and the 00:15 arrival)
- The departure time from London makes no sense as BA139 leaves LHR at 9:30am, not at 17h50
- That barcode is **obviously** from a parcel and **not** from a flight (online check ins give you a QR-like code, not a barcode)
  Paketpostzentrum roughly means parcel mail center, which is far from a flight barcode

If you have sent money, you will likely never get it back, depending on how you gave that money, contact them and file a police report

Comment: Googling "Paketpostzentrum" I found the source for the picture (at least that part): https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/File:Germany_stamp_type_PC-B3.jpg. The barcode is copied from there.

Comment: One more to add is that they put the flight number on "aircraft". And I don't think any airline would ever write "Boeing 747 Jet"; if anything, they would write "B748" or "Boeing 747-800".

Comment: @MartinArgerami: BA does display the flight number and aircraft name like that. Here's an [example](https://www.headforpoints.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/ba-flight-details-popup.png) and [source](https://www.headforpoints.com/2021/04/01/how-to-see-what-aircraft-type-is-operating-your-british-airways-flight/). That itself isn't suspicious.

Comment: @Wing: thanks for noticing. It does make me suspicious of whoever writes code for them and/or designs their UX, but it is certainly not a scam :D

Comment: @MartinArgerami: haha, don't disagree it's strange. I've noticed it is inconsistent as well. For the A321neo and Embraer E190SR, BA doesn't append "jet" after their names, even though they are both jet aircraft ‍♀️

Comment: @Wing I think it's a vestige from yesteryear when flying on a jet was like flying on the Concorde. That, and I see it in regional/commuter flights. The layperson can't tell whether an A220 or Q400 is jet or prop.

Comment: @Fabio The scammers probably googled bar code and copied the first image they've stumbled across.

Comment: Plot twist: OP could be the scammer itself and is looking for weaknesses in the fake ticket they created

Comment: Apart from the fact that Paketpostzentrum indicates a bar code from a parcel delivery center and not an airline it is also in German. A plane ticket by British Airways from India to the UK has no reason to have anything on it written in German, regardless of what the words mean.

Answer (score 35):

I agree with @Nicolas Formichella's answer that this is a scam. Don't send any (more) money.

Some more details:

- *Paketpostzentrum* is in German language, thus it cannot be relevant for a flight from the UK to India operated by British Airways. All captions should be in English.
- The plane ticket is way too expensive for 2910.12 GBP. A ticket for a non-stop one-way flight from LHR to BOM operated by British Airways, departing tomorrow can be booked for less than 600 GBP, and a round trip for less than 1000 GBP. Other airlines sell even cheaper non-stop tickets for this route. (I've just checked on [flights.google.com](https://flights.google.com/).)
- Plane e-tickets usually don't have any barcode, QR-code or rectangular code, but boarding passes do. The boarding pass is usually issued up to 24 hours before the flight departure, and has a caption saying *boarding pass* (rather than *ticket* or *trip summary*).
- Some boarding passes issued by some airlines do have regular barcodes. (However, a flight barcode with *Paketpostzentrum* next to it is a red flag. There are many other red flags as well in this case, see the answers and comments.)

Comment: The term *Paketpostzentrum* itsself is outdated. Paketzentrum is used mostly in Germany and Switzerland now. **Paketzentrum 15** would be Rüdersdorf (outside of Berlin)

Comment: A fully flexible ticket could be quite a bit more expensive (didn’t check), and the “ticket” says “selling class” (whatever that means) Y, which if it were a booking class would be fully-flexible non-discounted economy. But that’s about the only thing that could make sense on that “ticket”.

Comment: The kerning (letter spacing) on the word `CONFIRMED` is terrible, looks like a bad copy/paste.

Comment: @scunliffe All things considered, bad keming is probably the least suspicious thing here.

Comment: But several different typefaces and the kerning = cut n paste

Comment: @scunliffe Hardly an indication of legitimacy, but the word `CONFIRMED` isn't kerned at all because it's written in a fixed-width font. (It is an especially ugly fixed-width font though.)