# American with visa entry to France. May he land in Belgium when coming to Europe for the first time?

Tags: schengen-visas, france, us-citizens, tourist-visas, belgium

I am from Belgium.  I have an **American** friend who wants to travel in Europe.
He has a **tourist visa entry to France** (Schengen).
**May he land in Belgium when using his visa for the first time?**
I am offering him to stay at my address and we are planning on traveling together...

Comment: Is the **american** a US citizen? There are many countries in the Americas whos citizens that require a visa for the Schengen Area, but the US is not one of them. Offering such a 'friend' support may not be wise.

Comment: @Catou Guidance for US citizens on entering Belgium as a tourist is available here https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Belgium.html If your American is a (possibly recent) internet friend whom you’ve never met in person, please take care, I suggest you read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/my-online-friend-is-asking-for-money-in-order-to-visit-my-home-country-is-this If you’re 100% sure, see Q&As https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/schengen-overview-community-wiki-to-avoid-duplicates

Comment: Beyond the oddity of an American (assuming US) getting a Schengen visa, it's also odd to enter the Schengen area via Belgium. There are very few flights between Belgium and America: most travelers going to Belgium land in Amsterdam or Paris.

Comment: This question could use some clarification. ‘American’ is a generic in many parts of the world for anyone from the Americas, not just US citizens, and _the rules are different depending on the exact country of origin_. What you describe is fine for most Americans in many cases, but not all.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I doubt anyone from a western european country would use *American* to mean anything other than someone from the US.

Comment: @Traveller There’s not any guarantee that any arbitrary person reading the question knows that, and there is also a difference between someone being from the US (which is what most Europeans I’ve met mean when they say American) and someone who is an actual US Citizen. _Citizenship matters_ in this case, and the mention of a visa for an American visiting the Schengen area indicates that the American _might not be a US citizen_, hence my request for clarification.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Judging by comments from the OP on the first answer, the friend *is* a US citizen

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' it's not that odd. There are direct flights to Brussels, and there are connecting flights in non-Schengen countries other than the US. I just did a quick search from New York, where the least expensive flights were through Ireland, followed by direct flights, and from Boise, with connections through Toronto or Chicago. There was also an option entering Schengen in Germany. (I guess the Air France-KLM flights are all full for the dates I chose.) Anyway, it's clear that there will be a fair number of travelers from the US who do enter the Schengen area in Brussels.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - some of us remember Sabena rather fondly as a source of (relatively) cheap trans Atlantic flights...

Answer (score 22):

It's very odd for an American to have a tourist visa for France.  However, it's also true that people frequently use the term "tourist visa" to refer to the visa-free short stay that US citizens (and citizens of several other countries) are permitted under the Schengen regulations.

In general, though, anyone with a visa issued by any Schengen country can enter the Schengen area anywhere.  You can find people saying that the first entry must be through the country that issued the visa, but this is entirely incorrect.

It's possible for the visa to be territorially restricted, in which case he must of course abide by those restrictions.  These restrictions are unusual -- the regulation says that such visas are to be issued "exceptionally."

Some comments below are hinting at the possibility that this is a romance scam.  We see these from time to time.  It's possible that your question arises from the less-than-precise use of the term "visa" and that there's no need to be suspicious, but it's also possible that you're asking because someone is claiming some sort of false difficulty to gain your sympathy with the goal of taking advantage of you.  From what you've told us, it's difficult to say for sure, but it deserves to be mentioned explicitly for safety's sake.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Maybe I am not expressing myself well.
What I mean is that he applied for his visa at the French embassy/consulate.  
But for you, if he received his Schengen visa he can arrive in any country of the Schengen area?

Comment: @Catou I mean it's very odd for a US citizen to have a Schengen tourist visa of any description.

Comment: oh and why is that?  What should he have asked for?

Comment: @Catou It’s very odd because US citizens do not need a visa to enter the Schengen Zone as a tourist https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy/who-must-apply-schengen-visa_en How well do you know your American friend?

Comment: @Catou Traveller and Nicolas Formichella are right.  "What should he have asked for?": He needn't have asked for anything, normally.  In my (limited) experience, a US citizen approaching a French consulate for a tourist visa will be refused because a visa is not necessary and brings no benefit.  A visa would be needed for an intended stay of longer than 90 days.  Do you know whether it is a type C or type D visa?

Comment: Such an application would be considered **inadmissible** (the applicants citizenship doesn't require a visa for a short term (tourist) stay), therefore no decision on it could be made as to whether a visa would be issued or refused.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answers.  So an american citizen can travel to Europe with his passport only.  Right?  He won't be asked anything.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella 'reserved to very **specific** issues' : where in the Visa Code are these very specific issues defined for someone who **does not** require a visa in the first place?

Comment: @Catou he can be asked questions.  He has to be able to show that he meets the requirements, for example sufficient financial means.  They will also check an international database to see whether he is a fugitive from justice.  For the vast majority of US citizen entries into the Schengen area, this is a routine exchange along the lines of "what's the purpose of your trip, have a nice time," but it may be more involved, or less involved.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I don't really know, maybe for humanitarian/*force majeure* (like you are in the SIS for refusal of entry, and you can't enter normally, but you have a very compelling reason to get a LTV, you'll perhaps get issued one), yes I agree with everyone, if you don't need a visa, you won't be issued one

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Well, if you 'don't really know' you shouldn't claim that 'getting a tourist visa for Schengen as a visa-free passport holder is reserved to very specific issues' is possible. That how these 'hearsay' knowlage comes about.

Comment: @phoog and all, ok, thank you very much.  I will figure out all this with my friend as I am going to the us next week.  And as a EU citizen I needed an esta in order ton enter in the US ...

Comment: @Catou An ESTA does not by itself ensure you will be allowed to enter the US. An ESTA will allow you to fly to the US, where (at the US border) you may request entry. You're likely to be admitted to the US, but the ultimate decision rests with US Customs and Border Protection.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: @Catou But an ESTA is not a visa. Non-EU/EEA citizens will need an ETIAS to enter Schengen in a year or two, but American citizens still won’t need visas.

Comment: @Catou I assume you are trying to help your friend, but it would be better if you directed him to someone who actually *knows* what his visa requirements will be, rather than trying to piece together a solution from your own limited knowledge. Don't try to play the middleman here.

Answer (score 6):

As described in the other answer and comments, a US citizen does not need a visa to visit France or any other Schengen country, provided they adhere to the following rules (from memory):

- They intend to stay for less than 90 days
- On any day they are in the Schengen Area, they have not spent more than 90 days out of the last 180 inside Schengen
- They come for tourism, to visit friends or family, for business, and a number of other reasons which do not involve working while in the Schengen Area
- They have the means to support themselves during their stay
- They have the means to return home (or at least exit Schengen), usually taking the form of a return ticket
- They have travel insurance for the duration of their stay
- They are not considered dangerous or somehow undesirable.

Anyone coming under those conditions just needs their US passport and book a flight. Since one would not need a visa, one can enter the Schengen Area anywhere.

If your friend lives in the US but is not actually a US citizen, they may indeed need a visa. Such visas, while granted by one country, allow entry through any other country in the Schengen Area (of course if it doesn’t make any sense this may lead to issues, but entering via Belgium to get to France is not in this situation). One would still need to meet the requirements of the visa, including having a main purpose of stay/longest time spent in the country which issued the visa (you can’t get a visa from France and then just spend all your time in another country — at least on the first visit on that visa).

Likewise, if your friend has plans which go beyond a simple short stay (e.g. to take employment, for longer studies, to come live with someone…) then they do indeed need a visa, which would be a long-term national visa (type D). Those in general allow you to enter through anywhere in the Schengen Area as well, but again, one needs to follow the terms of the visa (there’s a lot of variety there).

So, in any case, with the exception of very specific and unusual circumstances, yes, they can enter via any Schengen country they want.

Comment: Your third bullet point is a bit misleading. As you know Schengen visa are certainly not tourist visas but it goes further that that. The thing about working is that it also requires permission that you are supposed to secure *before* getting the visa. It's unusual and honestly I have never anyone who has worked on a Schengen visa but you can find some references to that procedure in official documentation. The bottom line is that there are no separate categories or restrictive list of purposes, the Schengen regulations are intended to cover any and all short stays, no matter the purpose.

Comment: Also, travel insurance is a requirement anchored in the Visa Code. It is not mentioned in the Borders Code and doesn't concern people who travel visa free.

Comment: "of course if it doesn’t make any sense this may lead to issues" - it doesn't have to make _much_ sense though.  The visa has to be issued by the country where the holder plans to spend most of their time - but a visitor to Finland could choose to fly to Madrid and then make a rail trip to Helsinki.

Comment: As an American, I have entered the Schengen area on multiple occasions for short visits, and I have *never* been asked even so much as "business or pleasure?" They just stamped my passport and handed it back to me, every time. If you make a habit of staying for extended periods, or get yourself some kind of criminal record, then I imagine they get quite a bit more inquisitive, and the pandemic may have changed things since my last visit, but I simply cannot imagine an "average" American having significant problems entering Schengen unless they're either clueless or doing something illegal.