# Do you need to enter France directly for the visa to be valid?

Tags: france, student-visas

My wife's nephew is coming to stay with us (in France) to complete his studies.

The closest airport though is in Geneva, Switzerland. Does he have to land in France for the visa application to be accepted? If yes, is it acceptable for the flight to have stops in other countries?

Comment: What kind of visa does he have (type C or type D)? Or how long does he plan to stay in France? If the visa is already issued, are there restrictions written in the VALID FOR field?

Comment: I think Geneva has also an immigration and exit directly to France (the airport is in both countries). But also both are in Schengen area, so a Schengen visa should allow you to enter from Switzerland (but for some very special cases, where you will not found help here: really special cases).

Comment: The last two paragraphs of user jcaron's Answer in [this previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181288/american-with-visa-entry-to-france-may-he-land-in-belgium-when-coming-to-europe/181289#181289) are relevant to your questions. With a Type D Schengen visa, your wife's nephew can enter the Schengen area through any Schengen country. Because Switzerland and France are both in the Schengen area, the nephew can enter Schengen area via Switzerland.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi you can only exit to the "French sector" if you arrive from France. All other flights will get you to Switzerland first, but that really matters only for customs, for immigration it's just entry into Schengen in either case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quite generally:

- He can enter the Schengen Area at any point
- He can make as many stops as he wants outside or inside the Schengen Area. Stops outside the Schengen Area may have their own requirements for transit.

I'm not aware of any formalities at the point of entry (other than checking that the passport and visa are valid, of course). Depending on the length of the studies it may be necessary to validate the visa / convert to a residence permit once he is in France, but this does not happen at the border.

There may be a few very specific exceptions, but the consulate/embassy would probably have made that very clear if it were the case.

Comment: He doesn't have a VISA yet. The prefecture told him to come, get the inscription to the school, and then they will sort out the VISA

Comment: @algiogia what is his citizenship?

Comment: @algiogia: a long term visa may be done locally (e.g. for study), but you need to be able to enter in France (and Schengen area) (else you cannot take the flight).

Comment: @jcaron Mauritius. He can enter without applying for a VISA. Normally he would just need a document stating that he will stay at our home.

Comment: Why do so many people insist on spelling 'visa' in capital letters? It's not a credit card - that company is called 'Visa', although their logo is that word in all-capitals; I have, my bank tells me, a 'Visa debit card'.

Comment: @algiogia In that case it's still the same: he can enter the Schengen Area at any point of entry, and make as many stops as he wants.